# Writing a custom aspnet mvc action without an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm looking to write a custom route that would allow the following

http://localhost/blog/tags/foo

Currently this is what actually works

http://localhost/tags/Index/nhibernate

I've tried the following with no success - any help would be appreciated

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Tags",
    "{controller}/{id}",
    new { Controller = "Tags", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Tags",
    "blog/{controller}/{id}",
    new { Controller = "Tags", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use in your global.asax something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Tags",
                "blog/tags/{TagName}", 
                new { Controller = "Tags", action = "ShowTag", TagName = "" });
```

You'd then need a controller called 'TagsController.cs' with an ActionResult method called ShowTag plus a corresponding aspx called ShowTag.aspx. Your ShowTag method should look something like this:

```
public ActionResult ShowTag(string TagName)
{
    //do stuff here to get Id from tag name and get other data etc...
    return View();
}
```

Note that the order in which you map routes in the Global.asax.cs *does* matter.

Comment: dude, you fn rock!  Turns out the ORDER was the issue.  I put this Tags route first and all was good!  Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem, the order of routes has had me stumped a few times before!